# IAM Policy + S3 bucket tag conditions

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Attempting to use a tag at the bucket level to use in an IAM policy that would give individuals xyz access inside the bucket.  Seems like it should be possible: [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#object-keys-in-amazon-s3-policies).

Here is the actual [IAM policy](http://pastebin.com/gmzzpaYP):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:AssociateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:CreateCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:CreateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:CreateFlowLogs",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:CreateVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:CreateVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DeleteFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DisableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:EnableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifySubnetAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclAssociation",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:ReplaceRoute",
                "ec2:ReplaceRouteTableAssociation",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-9be6f38c",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-38cd975d",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-f595aae2",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-a38ad0c6",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-2ca0ef3b",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t2.micro",
                        "m3.medium",
                        "c4.xlarge"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "ec2:Tenancy": "default"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Team": "Network"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Team": "Network"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/Team": "Network"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aplpsecurity/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Symptoms are the user is unable to create a folder inside the bucket itself.

Answer (score 1):

[The AWS S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tagging-and-policies.html) notes that you cannot use the `s3:ExistingObjectTag/<tag-key>` condition with the `s3:PutObject` action:

> Object tags enable fine-grained access control for managing permissions. You can grant conditional permissions based on object tags. Amazon S3 supports the following condition keys that you can use to grant conditional permissions based on object tags:
>
> - `s3:ExistingObjectTag/<tag-key>` – Use this condition key to verify that an existing object tag has the specific tag key and value.
>
> **Note**
>
> When granting permissions for the `PUT Object` and `DELETE Object` operations, this condition key is not supported. That is, you cannot create a policy to grant or deny a user permissions to delete or override an existing object based on its existing tags.

Comment: It *is* possible. The `s3:ExistingObjectTag/` condition is indeed not supported for `PUT`, but `s3:RequestObjectTag/` is and fulfills the purpose.